# PHPMyAdmin not processing changes to table structure

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to change a field type in a table.  When I run the command

```
    ALTER TABLE `accounts` CHANGE `goldinbank` `goldinbank` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0';
```

and click Save, the operation is not processed, and PMA returns to the table structure without making changes.

Server: Localhost via UNIX socket

Server type: MySQL

Server version: 5.7.38 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Protocol version: 10

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to click run, not  save

Comment: @HunterD any error in HTTP response?

Comment: I don't have a run button.  Only a save button, next to the Preview SQL button.
No errors in the response.

Comment: Try ALTER TABLE `accounts` MODIFY `goldinbank` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'; If it does not work, this means some data on your column does not meet INT requirements.